# How do I auto equip items into empty inventory slots?

Tags: diablo-iii

Now that I've started my second character in Diablo 3, constantly opening my inventory to equip items into empty inventory slots has gotten pretty old. I'd rather it be automatic for that initial "I don't want to be naked" need for items. Is there a way to make this process automatic?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Options` > `Gameplay` > `Auto-equip Items`

[image]